# Unable to write more than 1000 records to HDFS hive table pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do some manipulation to a data set. You can see in the commented out part of the code if I do a LIMIT on the select to 1000 records the insert runs fine. This lead me to believe it was a memory issue. So far I have changed the following yarn-site.xml settings

```
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction = 0

spark.executor.overhead.memory = 1024

spark.driver.overhead.memory = 1024
```

My spark-submit looks as follows:

```
spark-submit transfer.py --num-executors 8 --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 4g --driver-memory 0 --executor-cores 4
```

Python code:
the table name and column names have been obscured in below code.

```
from os import getcwd
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.setAppName('spark-yarn')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import array

df = hive_context.table("schema.sourcedata")

df1 = df.groupBy('val1',).\
      agg(F.collect_set('val2').alias('val2'),
          F.collect_set('val3').alias('val3'),
          F.collect_set('val4').alias('val4'),
          F.collect_set('val5').alias('val5'),
          F.collect_list('val6').alias('val6'))

newDF = df1.repartition(3000)
#testdf2.count()
#df1.registerTempTable("temp_table")
#hive_context.sql("CREATE TABLE schema.table AS SELECT val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6 FROM temp_table LIMIT 100000") 
newDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schema.resulttable");
```

I am not getting an error right now just 199/200 task completed then it hangs for hours up to 15hours. The df is 910,000 rows and 6 columns wide.

Comment: probably you have skewed keys in the `val1` column that you group by

Comment: try doing hashPartition before groupBy step & proceed further without repartition